# AzureAD: Using long-lived refresh tokens for external API "system" consumers?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a bunch of APIs that will have both internal and external (to the company) consumers. I'm using AzureAD for authentication. Whilst these consumers will be integrations written in code, I don't want to have to create and manage dedicated "app registrations" for each client/consumer. I also want to be able to use roles for more granular permissions.

It *feels* like a long-lived refresh token is the best option for this, and I've written a working proof-of-concept for this, which meets the requirements perfectly.

Given this is security though - I wanted to ask if I'm doing anything stupid or wrong.

First question - is it okay to treat a refresh token as a long-lived secret that consumers can store in their secure config, then their systems programmatically use that to query an access token to use against our APIs?

If this is okay - my second question is regarding the client id and secret. Because the implicit flow doesn't support refresh tokens, I'm using the authorisation code-flow. For this, it looks like I have to pass the client-id and client-secret *as well as* the authorisation code or refresh token to AzureAD. This means that I need to create a dedicated "auth api" that the consumers call to request these tokens. This auth api literally just then makes a downstream call to AzureAD passing the clientid and secret (which the consumer obviously doesn't know about). It feels like if the implicit flow supported refresh tokens I wouldn't have to implement this "auth API" at all. But because I have to use the authorisation code flow - it's forcing me to implement a proxy "auth api" for all token requests to go through. Am I missing something - or is this the way I should be doing it? It's fine if so - as this is what my PoC is doing, and it's working. But again, just wanted a sanity check on this with it being security related.

Ps. I know Azure API Management gives a lot of this functionality - but for reasons out of scope of this question, this isn't a good fit for us.

### Update

To add another couple of reasons why this method fits my use-case really well...

- A lot of internal developers will also be using these APIs (internal to the company). They already have AzureAd accounts anyway. So this then becomes super-simple to manage - we just have a bunch of security groups with certain roles in the app registration, and we can just add devs to those groups. And they don't need to know the client id / secret - they just use their own user account.
- The APIs have Swagger UIs. Using users instead of clientid/secret - means developers can use the Swagger UIs with single sign on.

Answer (score 1):

**WEB CLIENTS**

So a web app is used by developers to sign in via their Azure AD account. Authorization Code Flow is fine, after which each user will get access tokens and refresh tokens for calling APIs. Tokens will include the user's role and APIs can use them for authorization.

**EXTERNAL API CLIENTS**

These might be B2B clients and therefore use the Client Credentials Flow. Tokens issued to these clients would then have no user context.

**INTERNAL API CLIENTS**

It is a little unusual for a developer to login to a web client and then take tokens issued and use them in other apps. This is partly about reliability and partly because different apps generally access different areas of data. See [this scopes article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) for details on designing how components call each other.

**REFRESH TOKENS**

A refresh token is something that will expire so you need a plan for this. Avoid using them in static configuration. Consumers need to handle refresh token expiry in order for their app to be reliable.

**CODED INTEGRATIONS**

Are these web clients or APIs, and how many distinct apps are there? It feels like combining these into one or a few client registrations is the right option. A common setup might work like this:

- All developers might share the same registration
- All web clients use the Authorization Code Flow - and you Auth API
- API clients forward tokens to other APIs, to maintain user context

Comment: Thanks for your post. I thought refresh tokens had a lifetime of 90 days though?
In my initial post, I'm using the term 'consumers' to refer to clients (don't really have a concept of users that aren't clients for this use case).
Using 'app registrations' for clients would cause a lot of managment headaches. I've just done an update to my original post mentioning a few more reasons why this work-flow would work really well for us. The method I've described is ideal for what we want - but I'm now concerned that I'm doing something non-standard :(

Comment: Just seen your update re. refresh tokens. Yeah, this is the only negative thing to the process - ie. the consumers will have to refresh their refresh token at a minimum of every 90 days (ideally more frequently). Also if they change their user password. I think this is better than managing app registrations for each and every client and internal developer though (and for each and every environment).